# AngularJS dynamic ng-include src do not work

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to do some AngularJs examples using dynamic `ng-include`, but it does not work.

Here is my example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="exampleApp">
<head>
    <title>Directives</title>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script>
        angular.module("exampleApp", [])
        .controller("defaultCtrl", function ($scope) {
            $scope.todos = [
            { action: "Get groceries", complete: false },
            { action: "Call plumber", complete: false },
            { action: "Buy running shoes", complete: true },
            { action: "Buy flowers", complete: false },
            { action: "Call family", complete: false }];

            $scope.viewFile = function () {
                return $scope.showList ? "list.html" : "table.html";
            };
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="todoPanel" class="panel" ng-controller="defaultCtrl">
          <ng-include src="viewFile()"></ng-include>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem I have is that neither of both pages `list.html` nor `table.html` is ever loaded

If I set static `<ng-include src="'list.html'"></ng-include>` it works fine.

It is a standard HTML page executing from Visual Studio and Internet Explorer.

I test it in `Chrome` and it Works... It does't work under `Internet Explorer`.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: It works fine here http://plnkr.co/edit/N7I0t5HLU4yhxu6fELV4?p=preview

Comment: thanks, but what I am missing in Angular configuration...? I have to include it in de IIS?

Answer (score 0):

First off I would not try to bind a function to a `ng-include`.

Instead I might make use of `ng-if`

```
<ng-include ng-if="showList" src="'list.html'"></ng-include>
<ng-include ng-if="!showList" src="'table.html'"></ng-include>
```